# ARM Template - Deployment template validation failed

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, azure-rm-template

after a lot of tries I just cannot seem to be able to figure out the problem with the below ARM Template for a Logic App. The error is pretty straight forward saying

`Deployment template validation failed: 'The resource 'Microsoft.Web/connections/msd-goal-activities-inbound' is not defined in the template. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-template for usage details.`

I do understand that this error typically shows up when there is a dependent resource which was created outside of this template, but the thing here is that this is a connection reference that I am trying to create as part of the template itself and is available in the resource.

```
    {
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "EnvName": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "https://something.com"
    },
    "EventHubTopic": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "msd-goal-activities-inbound"
    },
    "eventhubs_1_Connection_Name": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "msd-goal-activities-inbound"
    },
    "eventhubs_1_Connection_DisplayName": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "msd-goal-activities-inbound"
    },
    "eventhubs_1_connectionString": {
      "type": "securestring",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Azure Event Hubs Connection String"
      }
    },
    "commondataservice_1_Connection_Name": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "CDS-ApplicationUser"
    },
    "commondataservice_1_Connection_DisplayName": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "MSDApplicationUser"
    },
    "commondataservice_1_environment": {
      "type": "securestring",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Environment id"
      }
    },
    "commondataservice_1_token:clientId": {
      "type": "securestring",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Client (or Application) ID of the Azure Active Directory application."
      }
    },
    "commondataservice_1_token:clientSecret": {
      "type": "securestring",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Client secret of the Azure Active Directory application."
      }
    },
    "commondataservice_1_token:TenantId": {
      "type": "securestring",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "The tenant ID for the Azure Active Directory application."
      }
    },
    "commondataservice_1_token:resourceUri": {
      "type": "securestring",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "The resource you are requesting authorization to use."
      }
    },
    "commondataservice_1_token:grantType": {
      "type": "string",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Grant type"
      },
      "defaultValue": "client_credentials",
      "allowedValues": [
        "code",
        "client_credentials"
      ]
    },
    "commondataservice_1_privacySetting": {
      "type": "string",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Privacy Setting"
      },
      "defaultValue": "Organizational",
      "allowedValues": [
        "None",
        "Private",
        "Organizational",
        "Public"
      ]
    },
    "LogicAppLocation": {
      "type": "string",
      "minLength": 1,
      "allowedValues": [
        "[resourceGroup().location]",
        "eastasia",
        "southeastasia",
        "centralus",
        "eastus",
        "eastus2",
        "westus",
        "northcentralus",
        "southcentralus",
        "northeurope",
        "westeurope",
        "japanwest",
        "japaneast",
        "brazilsouth",
        "australiaeast",
        "australiasoutheast",
        "southindia",
        "centralindia",
        "westindia",
        "canadacentral",
        "canadaeast",
        "uksouth",
        "ukwest",
        "westcentralus",
        "westus2",
        "koreacentral",
        "koreasouth",
        "francecentral",
        "francesouth",
        "uaecentral",
        "uaenorth",
        "southafricanorth",
        "southafricawest",
        "switzerlandnorth",
        "switzerlandwest",
        "germanynorth",
        "germanywestcentral",
        "norwayeast",
        "brazilsoutheast",
        "westus3"
      ],
      "defaultValue": "[resourceGroup().location]"
    },
    "LogicAppName": {
      "type": "string",
      "minLength": 1,
      "defaultValue": "SendGoalTask"
    }
  },
  "variables": {},
  "resources": [
    {
      "properties": {
        "state": "Enabled",
        "definition": {
          "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
          "actions": {
            "Try": {
              "type": "Scope",
              "actions": {
                "If_Status_is_Delete,_send_Goal_Task_Delete": {
                  "type": "If",
                  "expression": {
                    "and": [
                      {
                        "equals": [
                          "@triggerBody()?['statuscode']",
                          644040000
                        ]
                      }
                    ]
                  },
                  "actions": {
                    "Compose_Goal_Task_Delete": {
                      "type": "Compose",
                      "inputs": {
                        "body": {
                          "contactId": "@triggerBody()?['_assigned_to_value']",
                          "msdTaskId": "@triggerBody()?['goal_taskid']"
                        },
                        "domain": "GOAL_TASK",
                        "operation": "DELETE",
                        "timestamp": "@string(utcNow())"
                      },
                      "runAfter": {}
                    },
                    "Send_delete_event": {
                      "type": "ApiConnection",
                      "inputs": {
                        "host": {
                          "connection": {
                            "name": "@parameters('$connections')['eventhubs']['connectionId']"
                          }
                        },
                        "method": "post",
                        "body": {
                          "ContentData": "@{base64(outputs('Compose_Goal_Task_Delete'))}"
                        },
                        "path": "/@{encodeURIComponent(parameters('EventHubTopic'))}/events"
                      },
                      "runAfter": {
                        "Compose_Goal_Task_Delete": [
                          "Succeeded"
                        ]
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  "runAfter": {},
                  "else": {
                    "actions": {
                      "Compose_Goal_Task": {
                        "type": "Compose",
                        "inputs": {
                          "body": {
                            "completedBy": "@if(equals(triggerBody()?['_completed_by_label'],null),'',triggerBody()['_completed_by_label'])",
                            "contactId": "@triggerBody()?['_assigned_to_value']",
                            "TaskId": "@triggerBody()?['consumer_task_id']",
                            "msdGoalId": "@triggerBody()?['_goal_value']",
                            "msdTaskId": "@triggerBody()?['goal_taskid']",
                            "owner": "@triggerBody()?['_ownerid_value']",
                            "status": "@if(equals(triggerBody()?['statecode'],1),'COMPLETED','ACTIVE')",
                            "summary": "@triggerBody()?['name']"
                          },
                          "domain": "GOAL_TASK",
                          "operation": "UPSERT",
                          "timestamp": "@string(utcNow())"
                        },
                        "runAfter": {}
                      },
                      "Send_event": {
                        "type": "ApiConnection",
                        "inputs": {
                          "host": {
                            "connection": {
                              "name": "@parameters('$connections')['eventhubs']['connectionId']"
                            }
                          },
                          "method": "post",
                          "body": {
                            "ContentData": "@{base64(outputs('Compose_Goal_Task'))}"
                          },
                          "path": "/@{encodeURIComponent(parameters('EventHubTopic'))}/events"
                        },
                        "runAfter": {
                          "Compose_Goal_Task": [
                            "Succeeded"
                          ]
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              },
              "runAfter": {}
            }
          },
          "parameters": {
            "$connections": {
              "defaultValue": {},
              "type": "Object"
            },
            "EnvName": {
              "defaultValue": "https://something.com",
              "type": "String"
            },
            "EventHubTopic": {
              "defaultValue": "msd-goal-activities-inbound",
              "type": "String"
            }
          },
          "triggers": {
            "When_a_row_is_added": {
              "type": "ApiConnectionWebhook",
              "inputs": {
                "body": {
                  "NotificationUrl": "@{listCallbackUrl()}"
                },
                "host": {
                  "connection": {
                    "name": "@parameters('$connections')['commondataservice']['connectionId']"
                  }
                },
                "path": "/datasets/@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent(parameters('EnvName')))}/tables/@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent('goal_tasks'))}/onnewitemswebhook",
                "queries": {
                  "scope": "Organization"
                }
              }
            }
          },
          "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
          "outputs": {}
        },
        "parameters": {
          "$connections": {
            "value": {
              "eventhubs": {
                "id": "[concat(subscription().id, '/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/', parameters('LogicAppLocation'), '/managedApis/', 'eventhubs')]",
                "connectionId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/connections', parameters('eventhubs_1_Connection_Name'))]",
                "connectionName": "[parameters('eventhubs_1_Connection_Name')]"
              },
              "commondataservice": {
                "id": "[concat(subscription().id, '/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/', parameters('LogicAppLocation'), '/managedApis/', 'commondataservice')]",
                "connectionId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/connections', parameters('commondataservice_1_Connection_Name'))]",
                "connectionName": "[parameters('commondataservice_1_Connection_Name')]"
              }
            }
          },
          "EnvName": {
            "value": "[parameters('EnvName')]"
          },
          "EventHubTopic": {
            "value": "[parameters('EventHubTopic')]"
          }
        }
      },
      "name": "[parameters('LogicAppName')]",
      "type": "Microsoft.Logic/workflows",
      "location": "[parameters('LogicAppLocation')]",
      "tags": {
        "CreatedOnDate": "2021-12-09T06:21:50.3621698Z",
        "Creator": "Piyush Paliwal",
        "displayName": "LogicApp"
      },
      "apiVersion": "2016-06-01",
      "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/connections', parameters('commondataservice_1_Connection_Name'))]",
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/connections', parameters('eventhubs_1_Connection_Name'))]"
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "MICROSOFT.WEB/CONNECTIONS",
      "apiVersion": "2018-07-01-preview",
      "name": "[parameters('eventhubs_1_Connection_Name')]",
      "location": "[parameters('LogicAppLocation')]",
      "properties": {
        "api": {
          "id": "[concat(subscription().id, '/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/', parameters('LogicAppLocation'), '/managedApis/', 'eventhubs')]"
        },
        "displayName": "[parameters('eventhubs_1_Connection_DisplayName')]",
        "parameterValues": {
          "connectionString": "[parameters('eventhubs_1_connectionString')]"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "MICROSOFT.WEB/CONNECTIONS",
      "apiVersion": "2018-07-01-preview",
      "name": "[parameters('commondataservice_1_Connection_Name')]",
      "location": "[parameters('LogicAppLocation')]",
      "properties": {
        "api": {
          "id": "[concat(subscription().id, '/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/', parameters('LogicAppLocation'), '/managedApis/', 'commondataservice')]"
        },
        "displayName": "[parameters('commondataservice_1_Connection_DisplayName')]",
        "parameterValues": {
          "environment": "[parameters('commondataservice_1_environment')]",
          "token:clientId": "[parameters('commondataservice_1_token:clientId')]",
          "token:clientSecret": "[parameters('commondataservice_1_token:clientSecret')]",
          "token:TenantId": "[parameters('commondataservice_1_token:TenantId')]",
          "token:resourceUri": "[parameters('commondataservice_1_token:resourceUri')]",
          "token:grantType": "[parameters('commondataservice_1_token:grantType')]",
          "privacySetting": "[parameters('commondataservice_1_privacySetting')]"
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "outputs": {}
}
```

Comment: hello @Piyush , can you please try using the latest template deployment schema `https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#` and also the api versions of web connections should be `2016-06-01` or `2015-08-01-preview` as per this [Microsoft Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.web/allversions#resource-types-and-versions)

Comment: Sure, let me try that. However a couple of other observations;
- We tried the same template using a different machine and it worked as it is
- this ARM template was generate automatically using the portal

Comment: No, doesn't help. Tried both these changes but still the same thing

Comment: Deploying via Visual Studio 2019 with a dedicated azure subscription. The only difference between the machines is the user

Comment: i guess the issue then can be narrowed to the access level permissions for both the users on the azure subscription

Comment: Both users have same permissions on Azure subscription. Could it be a cache thing?

Comment: i tried deploying the same with 2 users and it deploys successfully as well .. may be you are right , try clearing the cache once for the problematic machine.. but i am not sure if it will work or not

Comment: hello @Piyush , was the issue resolved?

Comment: Hi @AnsumanBal-MT, no man; something was weird and looks like a one time thing but this template is absolutely ok